# Under what conditions can I split a power of a binomial sum into two products?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-theorem

I was reading a paper and came across a section that claimed that if $y \in \mathbb{N}$, and if $x \in [0,1]$, then for the expression:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{x}{4}\right)^y
$$

there exists a $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{x_0}{4}\right)^y = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{y_1}\left(\frac{x_0}{4}\right)^{y_2}
$$

where $y = y_1 + y_2$.

I am not able to see how this is true. Is there such a way to prove this? thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you have faithfully reproduced the claim? As it is now stated in your question it is trivially true: just take $x_0=0$, $y_1=y$, $y_2=0$ (where $0^0=1$ is the accepted convention in algebraic notation). If it is required, say, that $0<x_0<1$ and that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are nonzero natural numbers, then life becomes perceptibly harder.

Comment: @chizhek $0^0 = 1??!!!$

Comment: In algebra it is an accepted convention that $x^0=1$, whatever the $x$. For example, a quadratic polynomial $1+x+x^2$ can be legitimately written as $x^0+x^1+x^2$. This is what Graham & Knuth & Patashnik have to say about this in Concrete Mathematics, p.162: "Some textbooks leave the quantity $0^0$ undefined, because the functions $x^0$ and $0^x$ have different limiting values when $x$ decreases to $0$. But this is a mistake. We must define $x^0=1$, for all $x$, if the binomial theorem is to be valid when $x=0$, $y=0$, and/or $x=-y$. The theorem is too important to be arbitrarily restricted!"